# how to use iframe in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I want to change scrollTop of iframe after load.
this is my idea.

in template

```
<iframe .. onload="{{loaded()}}" ..></iframe>
```

in controller

```
$scope.loaded = function() {
    //chage scroll of iframe
}
```

but I think this is not angular style("Do not Any kind of DOM manipulation")

what is the best practice do this?

Comment: A directive would be the best practice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

here is mycode. but cross-domain is not working..

```
directive('myIframe', function(){
    var linkFn = function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.find('iframe').bind('load', function (event) {
          event.target.contentWindow.scrollTo(0,400);
        });
    };
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: {
        src:'@src',
        height: '@height',
        width: '@width',
        scrolling: '@scrolling'
      },
      template: '<iframe class="frame" height="{{height}}" width="{{width}}" frameborder="0" border="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="{{scrolling}}" src="{{src}}"></iframe>',
      link : linkFn
    };
  });
```

Comment: This might be why cross domain is broke. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3679

Comment: I know it's an old question, but to get rid of cross-domain error you can make changes: `return { ... scope.src:'&src' ...}`,  `template: '<iframe src={{src()}}...'`. Then in the controller for myIframe: `$scope.getSrc = function() { return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://example.com"); };` and `<my-iframe src='getSrc()'>`

Comment: @Miquel Can you edit this answer with your changes or post a new answer so that others can also benefit from it..

Answer (score 6):

This is a workaround to avoid cross domain problems:

```
  directive('myIframe', function(){
    var linkFn = function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.find('iframe').bind('load', function (event) {
          event.target.contentWindow.scrollTo(0,400);
        });
    };
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: {
        src:'&src',
        height: '@height',
        width: '@width',
        scrolling: '@scrolling'
      },
      template: '<iframe class="frame" height="{{height}}" width="{{width}}" frameborder="0" border="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="{{scrolling}}" src="{{src()}}"></iframe>',
      link : linkFn
    };
  });
```

in controller ($sce injected):

```
$scope.getSrc = function() {
  return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://example.com");
};
```

and in .html:

```
<my-iframe src='getSrc()'>
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work, just have the `my-frame='loaded()'` in your iframe tag and it should work.  It is untested and I assume the load function is called after the frame is loaded.  If it doesn't work, maybe `ready` would work.

```
.directive('myFrame',function(){
    return {
        link:function(scope,ele,attrs){
            ele.load(function(){
                scope.$apply(attrs.myFrame);
            });
        }
    };
});
```